# Cambiar el formato del String que devuelve el tipo LocalDate

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, parsear, localdate

Tengo un proyecto en el que realizo una conexión con *MySQL* y trabajo con tipo de dato `Date`(en *MySQL*) y `LocalDate`( en *Java*)

Mi problema es el siguiente, el método `TryParseDate()` parsea de `String` a `LocalDate` y me devuelve la fecha con formato `yyyy-mm-dd` :

```
public static LocalDate TryParseDate(String text){

    LocalDate date=null;

    try{
        int dayOfMonth = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(0, text.indexOf('/')));
        int month = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(text.indexOf('/')+1,text.lastIndexOf('/')));
        int year = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(text.lastIndexOf('/')+1,text.length()));

        date=LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        return date;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

En MySQL el formato de la fecha es el siguiente: `dd/mm/yyyy` y entiendo que a la hora de aplicar los operadores de comparación entre los dos formatos, el programa no es capaz de comparar las fechas y omite dichas comparaciones (que alguien me corriga si me equivoco!)

Reproduzco este supuesto error a la hora de realizar esta consulta por medio de JDBC:

```
ResultSet habDispQuery= sqlconn.resultSetOfQuery("SELECT * FROM reservahotel.Habitacion WHERE ID_Habitacion NOT IN"
            + " (SELECT ID_Habitacion FROM reservahotel.Reserva"
            + " WHERE reserva.Fecha_inicio > '" + FechInicio + "' AND Fecha_inicio < '" + FechFinal + "'"
            + " OR Fecha_final <= '" + FechInicio + "' AND Fecha_final >= '" + FechFinal + "'"
            + " OR Fecha_final > '" + FechInicio + "' AND Fecha_final < '" + FechFinal + "'"
            + " OR Fecha_inicio > '" + FechInicio + "' AND Fecha_final <'" + FechFinal + "');");
```

Aclarando un poco, `resultSetOfQuery()` solo es un método que he implementado, que crea el `statement`, ejecuta la consulta y devuelve el objeto `ResultSet`

Llego a la conclusión de que puede ser un problema con el formato de la fecha debido a que una consultado con las fechas en formato `dd/mm/yyyy` , en lugar del tipo `LocalDate`, devuelve los resultados aplicando la condición `WHERE` satisfactoriamente.

**Mi duda es, ¿cómo podría conseguir que LocalDate devolviera la fecha en el formato **dd/mm/yyyy**?**

Comment: Por Dios, no armes consultas SQL dinamicas concatenando strings, tiene el peligro de SQL injections y ademas es fragil, aprende a usar prepared statements

Comment: Gracias por la advertencia, cambiado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalDate no tiene formato.
Puedes usar la clase DateTimeFormatter

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
String formattedLocalDate = localDate.format(formatter);
```

Aquí puedes ver la documentación:
[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)